# Spoiler Display Code

Tags: javascript

I have a question about your spoiler in this page:

http://jdownloader.org/download/index

When i click on **Windows** it *appears* a table but when i click on **Linux** the content of Windows *disappears*. I want create a spoiler like this but that the content of one spoiler *doesn't disappear* when i press another spoiler.

What exactly should I change in this code (html source)?

```
<div class="dokuwiki">
        <div class="right_page">
<div class="entry-content">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./JDownloader.org - Official Homepage_files/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">                                         
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".nonjs").removeAttr( "href"); //href is needed for users without JS
 $('.OS').click(function(){
 if($(this).find(".details").is(":visible"))
 {
   $(this).find(".details").not(":hidden").hide("slow");
   return true;
 }
 else
 {
   $(".OS").not(this).each(function(i) {
     $(this).find(".details").hide("slow");
   });
   $(this).find(".details").show("slow");
   return false;
 }
 });
 });
 </script>     
 <style type="text/css">
 <!--
.details {
display: none;
clear: both;
padding: 2px;
}
.nonjs{
    cursor:pointer;
}
img {
border: 0px;
}
-->
</style>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I noticed you have other questions from a while ago with answers that you have not accepted. If an answer solves your problem, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/188347).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".OS").not(this).each(function(i) {
    $(this).find(".details").hide("slow");
});
```

That part finds all the ones that are NOT the current (clicked) one and hides them.

Comment: I have another problem with this code. When i click **below** the spoiler (i have links) NOT the spoiler (Windows) the spoiler disappear although I have not clicked the spoiler..Why? How can i change **$('.OS').click(function(){**
?

Comment: That's because you're still clicking inside the `.OS` container. Instead, change your selector so it only show/hides when you click the image.

Comment: what code can i use to change the selector to show/hide only when i click the image? In my case i replace the image with simply text

Comment: I suggest you learn about [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) and [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). You want to select an image that's a **child** of a div with the `OS` class.